# Unity Animation Parameter type 'Damages' does not match

Tags: c#, unity3d

Parameter type 'Damages' does not match. виводит в консоль хоть он есть

https://ibb.co/9yv73yq фото помилки

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

public class Wood_Resources : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]bool OnTrigger = false;
    [SerializeField]private GameObject obj;
    [SerializeField]private int treeHealth;
    private float randX;
    private float randY;
    Vector2 whereToSpawn;
    public static int damage = 1;
    [SerializeField] private TMP_Text damageCount;
    [SerializeField] private Animator animator;
    void Update()
    {
        if (OnTrigger)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X))
            {
                treeHealth -= damage; ;
                if(animator.GetFloat("Damages") !=1)
                {
                    animator.SetFloat("Damages", 1);
                }
                StartCoroutine(AnimaTimer(1f));
            }
        }
        if (treeHealth <= 0)
        {
            randX = Random.Range(transform.position.x - 1, transform.position.x + 1);
            randY = Random.Range(transform.position.y - 1, transform.position.y + 1);
            whereToSpawn = new Vector2(randX, randY);
            Instantiate(obj, whereToSpawn, Quaternion.identity);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        damageCount.text = damage.ToString();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        OnTrigger = true;
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        OnTrigger = false;
    }
    IEnumerator AnimaTimer(float time)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);

        animator.SetFloat("Damages", 0);
    }

}
```

Помилка
Parameter type 'Damages' does not match.
UnityEngine.Animator:GetFloat (string)
Wood_Resources:Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Resources/Wood_Resources.cs:26)

https://ibb.co/bNprk70 - фото аниматора

https://ibb.co/zVKf0ZQ - фото аниматора

Помогите исправить

Comment: Я изминил вопрос

Comment: Вставьте изображения прямо в пост стредстами редактора, а не ссылками. Так же укажите в какой строке кода ошибка.